# ¿Cómo mostrar un checkbox marcado o no marcado al actualizar?

Tags: php, mysql

> Como muestra en la imagen ,al querer actualizar , los checkbox que estan marcados en la base de datos no me muestran como marcados a la hora de actualizar. 
>   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
>
> El input del checkbox

```
        <td>Vendible?</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="cboxvendibleEdit"  id="var6" />
        </td>



if (isset($_POST['xCodigo']))
{
    $id = $_POST['xCodigo'];
    $v0 = $_POST['xDescripcion'];;
    $v1 = $_POST['xpreciocompra'];;
    $v2 = $_POST['xprecioventa'];;
    $v3 = $_POST['xcombocategoria'];;
    $v4 = $_POST['xcombomarca'];;
    $v5 = $_POST['xcomboseccion'];;
    $v6 = ($_POST['cboxvendibleEdit']) ? 1 : 0;
    $conexion->edit($id,$v0,$v1,$v2,$v3,$v4,$v5,$v6);


$('#actualizar').on('click', function(){
    var v0 = $('#var0').val();
    var v1 = $('#var1').val();
    var v2 = $('#var2').val();
    var v3 = $('#var3').val();
    var v4 = $('#var4').val();
    var v5 = $('#var5').val();
    var v6 = $('#var6').val();
        if (v0.length>0) { //valida requerido
            $('#xmensaje').html('<p></p>');
            var xparametros = $('#formUpdate').serialize(); 
            $.ajax({  //envia POST a otro php
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'item.iud.php',
                data: xparametros,
                success: function(data){
                    var url = document.URL;
                    location.href = url;
                }
            });
        } 
        else {
            $('#xmensaje').html('<p class="alert alert-danger">Faltan algunos datos!</p>');
        }
});
```

Comment: ¿En que momento rellenas los valores del formulario desde la base de datos?

Comment: Al ver que haces una redirección dentro del `success` de Ajax, comprendo que quizá no estás aprovechando una de las principales ventajas de Ajax, que es actualizar la información sin recargar la página. No sé lo que ocurre exactamente en la base de datos, pero si lo que haces es actualizar el registro para que sea vendible, deberías usar el `sucess` para cambiar el estado del checkbox, en vez de hacer una redirección.

Comment: Como puedo hacer que desde el input, me cargue el formulario con el checkbox si es 1 que se mantega marcado al editar y vacio si es un 0.

Comment: te sugiero revisar esto: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16239756/5215609

Comment: En tu código no queda claro cómo creas los elementos, por lo que es difícil responderte. Si recuperas el valor aquí, según parece: `$v6 = ($_POST['cboxvendibleEdit']) ? 1 : 0;` puedes manejar una variable, por ejemplo: `$checked= ($v6==1) ? "checked" : "";` y luego al crear el checkbox, algo como esto:  `$checkbox="<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"cboxvendibleEdit\"  id=\"var6\" $checked />";` Haciendo eso, tendrás en `$checkbox` el elemento creado con la etiqueta `checked` o no según el caso. El problema, como digo, es que el código que muestras no indica muy claramente la lógica que sigues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

si la validación la haces con **Jquery**, yo lo haría así:

```
if($(v6).val() == 1){
  $('#var6').prop('checked', true);
}
else{
  $('#var6').prop('checked', false);
}
```

si la validación la haces con **PHP**, así:

```
$var6 = $_POST['cboxvendibleEdit'];
$marcarCheckbox = 'checked';

if($var6 == 1){
  echo '<input type="checkbox" id="var6" $marcarCheckbox>';
}
else{
  echo '<input type="checkbox" id="var6">';
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por su tiempo ! Ya funciona lo que queria.

Comment: Ok Alexis, con gusto, me alegra haber podido ayudar!